# QT C++ module is not installed

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to QT. I am writing a demo C++ program integrating to QT. It got the module is not installed error all the time, even I tried several tricks from internet post.

I downloaded the latest QT package from the website.
QT Creator: 4.7.0, 
QT 5.11.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit),
Windows 10 PC

Appreciate for any advice.....

Here is the code:

```
//myclass.h
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
Q_INVOKABLE QString sayHello() const;
};
//myclass.cpp
#include "myclass.h"
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{
}
QString MyClass::sayHello() const
{
return "Hello!";
}

//main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include "QQmlContext"
#include "QQmlEngine"
#include "myclass.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("com.mycompany.myapplication", 1, 0, "MyClass");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
MyClass myClass;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myClass", &myClass);
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
}

//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import com.mycompany.myapplication 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")
Text {
  anchors.centerIn: parent
text: myClass.sayHello()
}
}

// myclass.pro
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += main.cpp 
myclass.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
HEADERS += myclass.h
```

Comment: Is it the case that when you run your program from Qt Creator it works, but not when launching from Windows?

Comment: Not working from Qt Creator either.  I also tried the QT C++ sample code on the official  QT website "BackEnd",  nothing works.    I think it may relate to the latest  QT framework upgrade.   The same code was working in  October before I was forced to upgrade to  QT Creator 4.7

Comment: You probably need to re-install Qt.

Comment: It could be the same stupid issue as happened with me before couple of days  -) In the installer by default the checkbox of Qt Framework version selection is unchecked. So you could just press Next and voila!, you have QtCreator installed without Qt itself.

Comment: I downloaded from https://v-play.net/download/  windows installation, nowhere to choose QT. The pure QT module still works fine; only custom C++ module stop working, cannot find the module.....